# Implementing an animated boot splash image in linux-live kit scripts

Tags: linux, bootsplash

I am using [linux-live kit](https://www.linux-live.org/) to produce a debian live distribution. However at the moment, the boot process involves only text output with a lot of [OK]. I would like to create a boot splash animation while the system is initialising instead of all this text output. Sort of like Zorin, Kali etc that show a logo while the system is booting.

The initramfs image is created on the fly to allow for bundles overlays. You can view all the code here: https://github.com/Tomas-M/linux-live and specifically here: https://github.com/Tomas-M/linux-live/tree/master/initramfs

How can I modify the `initramfs_create` script in order to implement plymouth boot animation? I already chose the animation I want.

PS: I am not asking for ready-made code but just steps that I need to follow in order to add plymouth implementation in the generated initramfs image.

Comment: what *is* an *animated splash image*? When is it shown, what does it show? On what platform?

Comment: @AdminBee I know at least 3 *very* distinct things that I would call a "boot splash image", and so I'll say: might be an established term, but it's not *specific* enough. Does OP want to use a linux tool to set the firmware splash image? Does this mean the grub / other bootloader spash image? Or the image displayed while linux is going through initialization (e.g. systemd boot)? Or what is shown by the user login manager (e.g. kdm)? Or after graphical login (e.g. by Plasma)? all these could reasonably be called "boot splash image".

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think we can rule out the first option, as that would be before the kernel or any shell script are launched. The third one could be, although I would consider it already a misunderstanding to call this a boot splash image (then again, its my personal opinion). Perhaps the best option is to close the question for "needs details or clarity".

Comment: By animated splash image, I mean the image displayed while linux is going through initialization. I will modify my initial question and even add more information so that you could guide me better.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays this functionality is no longer necessarily incorporated into the Linux kernel itself, but implemented as one service during startup.

One of the easier ways to achieve it is to install `plymouth`. On Debian-based systems, you should be able to get it via

```
sudo apt install plymouth
```

There are already a lot of pre-made static and animated splash images, available e.g. in the `plymouth-themes` package, but you can also create you own. Have a look at [this Q&A on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/143330/1127743) for more information.

Comment: I have modified the initial question and specified more details. Maybe you can understand better what I mean now.